# Can I run python package with C++ dependencies, without C++ installed on local device?

Tags: python, c++, linux

Recently I needed to use Python package with C++ and Eigen (C++ lib) dependencies. Unfortunately on Linux device, where I want to perform calculations on Python, I don't have root permissions. I can only install packages on Conda environment. Is there any way to make this package run?

Python package: https://github.com/BOBO1997/libs_qrem
Linux device is Lab on IBM Quantum platform: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/

Comment: C++ is not something you can "install". C++ is compiled into binaries, and you can pretty much run that on any device. So only if you still need to compile your C++ into binaries, you need gcc or g++ (or any other compiler). Please elborate on why it is a problem that you do not have root permissions.

Comment: Install the C++ toolchain in a directory that doesn't require root permissions.

Comment: Simple : Run ldd : `$ ldd libs_qrem.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` to know that `libstdc++.so.6` is required. ........ Eigen is not a library. Eigen is headers = text files only.